# Screen light up slowly due to low priority of systemserver

Tags: android, thread-priority

When I installed 30 more apps on my android devices, the screen light up time expires 3s.
Using **adb shell ps -t -p** to checkout the priority of threads:

> USER      PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS  PRIO  **NICE**  RTPRI SCHED  WCHAN
>   PC  NAME   system    553   1     6964   856   20    **0**     0     0 
>   poll_sched 00000000 S /system/bin/imsdatadaemon
>   system    893   380   1229888 92080 18    **-2**    0     0    SyS_epoll_ 00000000 S system_server
>   u0_a94    8515  380   1199228 38548 12    **-8**    0     0    SyS_epoll_ 00000000 S com.baidu.netdisk
>   u0_a97    10901 380  848872 98740 12    **-8**    0     0     SyS_epoll_ 00000000 Scom.hiapk.marketpho

Nice value(priority) of many apps are higher than system_server, which prepares the showing interface when light up screen. I think this result in system_server taking more time to light up screen. In logcat:

```
01-04 08:02:01.733   893  1276 I DisplayPowerController: Unblocked screen on after 2740 ms
```

To solve the problem, I want to improve the priority of system_server(original it is **THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND**), will any things goes wrong in this way?

```
public final class SystemServer {
    private void run() {
        ......
        // Ensure binder calls into the system always run at foreground priority.
        BinderInternal.disableBackgroundScheduling(true);

        // Prepare the main looper thread (this thread).
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(
                android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
        android.os.Process.setCanSelfBackground(false);
        Looper.prepareMainLooper();

        // Initialize native services.
        System.loadLibrary("android_servers");
        ....
     }
}
```